# ConTeXt: Why are my start-stop frames offset to the right?

Tags: context, framed

In my MWE, I place 4 frames on the layer in 4 different ways. The 2 frames from the start-stop versions of the command are offset about 1.5 mm to the right of the other 2 frames. Why?

[image]

```
\showframe
\setuplayout[backspace=58mm, width=106mm, header=0mm, footer=5mm, leftmargindistance=5mm, leftmargin=32mm, topspace=20mm, height=220mm, footerdistance=5mm,]

% layer covers margin and body text
\definelayer[postlayer][x=21mm, y=\topspace, width=100mm, height=\makeupheight,] 
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=postlayer,] 

\defineframedtext[mycaption]

\starttext
\dorecurse{1}{\input{knuth} }

% layer with framedtext

\setlayer[postlayer][hoffset=0mm, voffset=0mm,]
    {\framedtext
        [width=\leftmarginwidth, height=20mm, frame=on, offset=0mm,]
        {Text in the margin. } 
    }
% use start/stop
\setlayer[postlayer][hoffset=0mm, voffset=25mm,]
    {\startframedtext
        [width=\leftmarginwidth, height=20mm, frame=on, offset=0mm,]
        {Text in the margin. } 
    \stopframedtext
    }
    
\setlayer[postlayer][hoffset=0mm, voffset=50mm,]
    {\mycaption
        [width=\leftmarginwidth, height=20mm, frame=on, offset=0mm,]
        {Text in the margin. } 
    }
% use start/stop
\setlayer[postlayer][hoffset=0mm, voffset=75mm,]
    {\startmycaption
        [width=\leftmarginwidth, height=20mm, frame=on, offset=0mm,]
        {Text in the margin.} 
    \stopmycaption
    }
        
\stoptext
```

Comment: Unrelated to the problem: You do not need to put the content in braces inside the \startframedtext \stopframedtext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a ConTeXt bug. Minimal example:

```tex
\showmakeup[space]
\starttext
\hbox{.\startframedtext.\stopframedtext}
\stoptext
```

You can apply this patch to fix it:

```
--- texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkxl/pack-rul.old    2022-12-21 19:12:14.790830416 -0700
+++ texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkxl/pack-rul.mkxl   2022-12-21 19:12:26.193652551 -0700
@@ -2693,7 +2693,7 @@
 
 \tolerant\protected\def\pack_framed_text_start[#1]#*[#2]#*[#3]% or #1#*[#2]#*[#3]% and pass {#1}
   {\bgroup
-   \edef\currentframedtext{#1}
+   \edef\currentframedtext{#1}%
    \doifelseassignment{#2}
      {\pack_framed_text_start_indeed\empty{#2}}
      {\pack_framed_text_start_indeed{#2}{#3}}}
```

[I've reported this to the developers](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2022/107456.html), so if you don't want to patch your ConTeXt files, you can just wait a couple of days and update.

Comment: Thank you for that.

Comment: [Fixed in the latest upload](https://github.com/contextgarden/context/commit/e3b494#diff-154382deac9fc015b384b4cadedec5e36f102d3621ae585a4e5fa2a434d03701R2697)